# XHTML / HTML / CSS or HTML5 and CSS3

Tags: css, html

Should I learn HTML / XHTML / CSS first, or should I just dive into HTML5 and CSS3? I am a bit confused about this process. I do know basic HTML / CSS, but am planning on re-learning everything these next few weeks, and have not done this since high school.

Comment: This question fits better on [DocType](http://doctype.com/) or [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, HTML5 supercedes XHTML ([see interview with HTML spec lead, Ian Hixson](http://xhtml.com/en/future/conversation-with-x-html-5-team/)) so go for (X)HTML5 (the X has been dropped)

Secondly, HTML5 should be viewed more as a 'collection of features' rather than one spec. There will be no HTML 6 -- more, what features you support for HTML5 should be driven by your target browser set's [adoption of that specific feature](http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus#target-selector) rather than anything that 'supports HTML5' as this doesn't really mean anything any more

Comment: The "X" hasn't precisely been dropped from HTML 5.  HTML 5 has an HTML mode and an XML mode which are not the same, and XHTML5 indicates that you are using the XML mode.

Answer (score 0):

As for learning, you should definitely have a handle on HTML and CSS, before jumping into HTML5 and CSS3. Although you can learn HTML and CSS through the new versions, a lot of the new features are not consistently implemented throughout the browsers. I would say that picking up the basics of the current version would make things a little easier to grasp.

HTML has not changes the way HTML is written or rendered, and although there are some [deprecated features](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/) it is pretty much backward compatible. The main changes are really additions of features.

CSS3 is similar with a lot of new features, but little change to the structure and implementation.

Answer (score 0):

html5 is a set of 'add ons' that can be used with xhtml if you want.

CSS3 is a set of 'add ons' that can be ued with previous CSS.

So, they are one and the same in the broad sense.